# TV Distance between Bernoulli and Poisson

Tags: probability, statistics, total-variation

With P=Ber(p) and Q=Poiss(p) where $p\in (0,1)$, I try to find the TV Distance T(P,Q).

To find the Total Variance Distance we can use the discrete formula

$$T(P,Q) = 1/2 * \sum_{x\in E} |p_\theta(x) - p_{\theta'(x)}|$$

which I translate to
$$ T(P,Q) = 1/2 * \sum_0^\infty |p^x (1-p)^{1-x} - \frac{p^x*e^{-p}}{x!}|$$

I then take the seperate case $x=0$ out of the summation and get
$$=1/2 * |(1-p)-e^{-p}| + 1/2 * \sum_1^\infty |p^x (1-p)^{1-x} - \frac{p^x*e^{-p}}{x!}|$$

where due to probability $p\in (0,1)$ the second term is 1-P(x=0), therefore
$$=1/2 *( |(1-p)-e^{-p}| + |1- (1-p)+e^{-p}|)$$
$$=1/2 *( |(1-p)-e^{-p}| + |p+e^{-p}|)$$

But it seems I am making a mistake somewhere, as it doesn't seem correct.

Answer (score 1):

You've made a few mistakes here.  First, $P(x)=p^x(1-p)^{1-x}$ only for $x=0$ and $x=1$, so this term shouldn't be part of the summation for $x>1$.

Second, you say, "the second term is $1-P(X=0)$".  What random variable is $X$ supposed to be?  It looks like you're assuming that there's random variable $X$ with:
$$P(X=x) = \left|p^x(1-p)^{1-x}-\frac{p^xe^{-p}}{x!}\right|$$
so you can use the identity $\sum_1^\infty P(X=x) = 1 - P(X=0)$, but there is no such random variable, because for this "probability", we have $\sum_0^\infty P(X=x) \neq 1$.  This is true even if you fix the first problem and get rid of the erroneous $p^x(1-p)^{1-x}$ term for $x>1$.

That said, your overall approach isn't too bad.  Try separating out the *two* cases where $x=0$ and $x=1$, noting that for $x>1$, only the Poisson probability is left:
$$\sum_{x=2}^\infty \left|\frac{p^xe^{-p}}{x!}\right|$$
where the absolute value has no effect, so you now have a summation of Poisson probabilities.

Comment: Great, I see your point with the Bernoullis only being 0 and 1. Therefore for x=0 and x=1 I constructed the variation of the pmfs as follows

$x=0$: $\frac{1}{2}*|(1-p)-e^{-p}|$

$x=1$: $\frac{1}{2}* |p-p*e^{-p}|$

Now for $x>1$ I know the difference is just the CDF of the Poisson distribution (as Ber is null over 1), which converges to 1 as n goes to infinity. Therefore I can take 1 - pmf(x=0) - pmf(x=1) and get

$$1-\frac{1}{2}*(|(1-p)-e^{-p}|-|p-p*e^{-p}|)$$

Seems like I am not completely correct here with my answer.

Comment: For $x>1$, the difference is an infinite sum of Poisson probabilities, but not *all* of them.  It's the sum of probabilities for $x\geq 2$ only, so the infinite sum doesn't converge to 1, it converges to 1 minus the missing probabilities.